# MDX Measure from dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, dimensions, measure

I'm having an issue with my OLAP cube in Analysis Service server 2012.

I have fact table:

```
Unimonth ( Year * 100 + Month)
ID product
Sales Units
```

And dimension products

```
ID product
Grammage
Multipack
```

And I want to create measure (or calculated member) with this formula =

```
Sales Units * Grammage * Multipack
```

For now i created measure based on dimension products. It's call Volume and formula is =

```
Grammage * Multipack
```

Now I can do calculated member

```
Volume * Sales Units
```

But it is based on dimension products.. so if i have 3 products and only one have some sale units, it's still calculating 3 times.

Can anyone help me with that. I want to create calculated member which calculate the amount of sales volume. But I don't really know how to do it.

In SQL the query looks like this

```
SELECT Unimonth, fact_table.ID product, 
    SUM(Sales Units * Grammage * Multipack) AS Sales Volume 
FROM fact_table 
    INNER JOIN dimension_products 
        ON fact_table.ID product=dimension_products.ID product
GROUP BY Unimonth, fact_table.ID product
```

Thanks for help. I am drowning in MDX and OLAP Cubes in Analysis Service

Comment: can you put this calculation `SUM(Sales Units * Grammage * Multipack)` in your fact table as a new column - then just use it as a measure in OLAP ?

Comment: I agree with @whytheq that the place to do this is pre-olap.   In addition to adding it to your Fact table, you also have the option of doing it in a view on top of your Fact table, and getting your Measure Group from the view, or you could do it in the Data Source View in the SSAS database.